# Multiple Filter condition in scala and in and not in clause filter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, conditional-statements, in-clause

I am trying to do a filter similar to below using scala

where col1 = 'abc'
and col2 not in (0,4)
and col3 in (1,2,3,4)

I tried writing something like this

```
val finalDf: DataFrame = 
    initDf.filter(col("col1") ="abc")
          .filter(col("col2") <> 0)
          .filter(col("col2") <> 4)
          .filter(col("col3") = 1 ||col("col3") = 2 ||col("col3") = 3 ||col("col3") = 4)
```

or

```
val finalDf: DataFrame = 
     initDf.filter(col("col1") ="abc") 
     && col("col2") != 0 && col("col2") != 4 
     && (col("col3") = 1 
     || col("col3") = 2 
     || col("col3") = 3 
     || col("col3") = 4))
```

both not seems to be working. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For col operators are a little bit different

For equality use ===

For Inequality =!=

If you want to use literals you can use lit function

Your example may look like this

```
dfMain.filter(col("col1") === lit("abc"))
          .filter(col("col2") =!= lit(0))
          .filter(col("col2") =!= lit(4))
          .filter(col("col3") === lit(1) || col("col3") === lit(2) ||col("col3") === lit(3) ||col("col3") === lit(4))
```

You can also use isin instead of this filter with multiply ors

If you want to find more about operators for cols you ca read this

[Medium blog post part1](https://medium.com/@achilleus/https-medium-com-achilleus-a-practical-introduction-to-sparks-column-3f5fe83125c9)

[Medium blog post part2](https://medium.com/@achilleus/a-practical-introduction-to-sparks-column-part-2-1e52f1d29eb1)